# how to get suppliers name with some table with where

Tags: sql

I have three tables The first table of suppliers The second table of parts The third table is the suppliers of parts

I want to find the names of the suppliers whose city is the same as the city of the red piece. please help.

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.) Also show us your current query attempt. [mcve].

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you even write a query to get the cities for red parts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sname from S inner join sp on s.s#=sp.s#
inner join p on sp.p#=p.p# and s.city=p.city
```